# How can I hide the grub menu when the systems boots?

Tags: grub2, 14.04

How can I hide the grub2 menu when a Ubuntu system boots?

Comment: Cross posted (alreay answered) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137856/how-hide-the-grub-start-up-screen-in-debian-during-bootup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean boot menu of grub2, you can do this :

- Open file `/etc/default/grub` in any text editor, with su priviliegies.
- Find option `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false`, and change it to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`
- Save the file, and run `sudo update-grub`